# How to extract a single line from a list delimited with Carriage returns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of lines in a variable as follows:

```
var crDelimited = "Hello \n Bye \n extract me \n I stay"
```

Somehow I would like to extract the third line from crDelimited

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will give you the third line, or `undefined` if there are fewer than three lines:

```
crDelimited.split("\n")[2]
```

Or if you want to do something with the other lines too then keep a reference to the array of lines returned by `.split()`:

```
var lines = crDelimited.split("\n");    
// lines[2] would be the third line
```

Comment: What if the line was like this: {'Date': 'current', 'Idx': 'S&P500', 'DateJ': '2007-03-09'} \n {'Date': '2008-06-25', 'Idx': 'RCGlobal', 'DateJ':'2007-12-19'} \n {'Date': 'current', 'Idx': 'S&P500', 'DateJ': '2007-03-09'} \n {'Date': '2008-06-25', 'Idx': 'RCGlobal', 'DateJ': '2007-12-19'}

Comment: _"What if the line was like this..."_ - It doesn't make sense to have a "line" with newline characters in it. If you mean "What if the source string was like this..." then the second line would be the string `" {'Date': 'current', 'Idx': 'S&P500', 'DateJ': '2007-03-09'} "`.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized I was dealing with a string object not a string.  But your answer is good and accepted...